# Maximum Likelihood Function

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Suppose the random variables $X_1, X_2, . . .X_n$ are independent each with the distribution

$$f(x;\theta) = \frac{\theta \ x^{\theta-1}}{3^\theta} \ \ \text{ for} \ \  0 \leq x \leq 3.$$

Find the Maximum Likelihood estimate for $\theta$.

Comment: The likelihood function is $L(\theta)=f(x_1,\theta)f(x_2,\theta)...f(x_n,\theta)=\theta^n(x_1x_2...x_n)^{\theta-1}/3^{n\theta}$.

As it is often the case it is easier to maximize $$\ln\left(L(\theta)\right)=n\ln(\theta)+(\theta-1)\ln(x_1x_2...x_n)-n\theta\ln(3)$$

Take derivatives and equate to zero

$$0=\frac{n}{\theta}+\ln(x_1x_2...x_n)-n\ln(3)$$

We get that $$\theta=\frac{n}{n\ln(3)-\ln(x_1x_2...x_n)}$$

Comment: You have been asking 5 questions in a 7 hours time slot... Don't you think it's time to slow down ? We do not help you on the long term by serving you solutions on a tray. In this example, it is very strange that you haven't reached the step $\ln\left(L(\theta)\right)=n\ln(\theta)+(\theta-1)\ln(x_1x_2...x_n)-n\theta\ln(3)$ given by Mlazhinka etc...